# Discrete Distribution Help

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If p(n) = c(5/8)^n, 3 <= n <= infinity is a p.m.f. for a discrete random variable X, find (a) c, (b) the probability P(6 <= X <= 16), (c) the mean and (d) the variance

Here's my work. I think got c wrong and haven't gone past it.

(a) Since the sum of p(n) = 1, I got c(5/8)^1 + c(5/8)^2 + the sum from 3 to infinity of c(5/8)^n = 1. (I figured that because p(n) started at 3 I need to add the first 2 terms). I got (5/8)c + (25/64)c + (1000/1536)c = 1. Which reduces to 1560/2560 = 39/64 = c.

(b) Would I just added up c(5/8)^6 + c(5/8)^7 + ... c(5/8)^16?

(c) Would I just find the expected value E(X) = (x)p(n) from 3 to infinity (using the geometric series?)

(d) Would I just find E(x^2) + ((E(X))^2)?

Sorry for the formatting, I haven't learned LaTeX

Comment: You want $c[(5/8)^3+(5/8)^4+(5/8)^5+\cdots]=1$. Bring out a common factor $(5/8)^3$. We want $c(5/8)^3[1+(5/8)+(5/8)^2+\cdots]=1$. So we want $c(5/8)^3(8/3)=1$. That gives $c=192/125$.

Comment: Have you done the theory for **geometrically** distributed random variables? If so, can "borrow" from there, get very quick answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. $$\underset{n=3}{\overset{\infty }{\mathop \sum }}\,c{{\left( \frac{5}{8} \right)}^{n}}=1\Rightarrow c\cdot {{\left( \frac{5}{8} \right)}^{3}}\left( 1+\frac{5}{8}+\ldots  \right)=1\Rightarrow c\cdot {{\left( \frac{5}{8} \right)}^{3}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{5}{8}}=1\Rightarrow c=\frac{192}{125}$$

b. $$\underset{n=6}{\overset{16}{\mathop \sum }}\,\frac{192}{125}{{\left( \frac{5}{8} \right)}^{n}}$$

c. $$E\left( N \right)=\underset{n=3}{\overset{\infty }{\mathop \sum }}\,\frac{192}{125}\cdot n\cdot {{\left( \frac{5}{8} \right)}^{n}}$$

d. $$E\left( {{N}^{2}} \right)=\underset{n=3}{\overset{\infty }{\mathop \sum }}\,\frac{192}{125}\cdot {{n}^{2}}\cdot {{\left( \frac{5}{8} \right)}^{n}}$$ and $$Var\left( N \right)=E\left( {{N}^{2}} \right)-{{\mu }^{2}}$$

for sums you can use
$$1+x+{{x}^{2}}+\ldots =\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$1+2x+3{{x}^{2}}+\ldots =\frac{1}{{{\left( 1-x \right)}^{2}}}$$
 (derivatives).